How to add a collection / array variable in Camunda 7 console
I have a basic Camunda 7 setup on Apache tomcat and am currently trying to experiment with Parallel Multi Instance task. But for the most basic part which is about having a collection. I am absolutely unable to add a Collection variable through the console. I get the following error in the console for the input below.

I have combed through every resource and answer I could find online for a couple of days now. All say that the inputs are right but it just doesn't work.
I have tried ArrayList instead of just List.
One of the attempts at debugging I was able to get a stringified Array through as a "String" variable and deserialize it using a execution listener on the sequence flow to the collection. This works as a test but in my final solution due to the architecture (and IP considerations) I cant setup such execution listeners.
Thus I really need to understand what is it that I have missed in order to just add a collection variable through the console.
P.S. This is my first S.O. question and also I'm a noob in Camunda so please help me update the details if needed.

It seems to be an open issue with the Camunda tasklist not escaping the string value correctly.
Please see here for reference:
https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform/issues/2576
As Camunda is focussing on developing Camunda 8, I'm not sure whether this bug will be fixed at all.
